# Django url/route order not maintained

Tags: django, url-routing

I have the following in my root URLconf module (there's more, but not important, so left out):

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^password-reset-redirect-view/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
            password_reset_redirect,
            name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
    path('', include('search.urls')),
    path('', include('customer_portal.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

Here's the **customer_portal.urls**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('customer/contact/', views.contact),
    path('', views.home),
    re_path(r"^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", views.email_verification,
        name="account_confirm_email"),
]
```

Here's the **rest_auth.registration.urls**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RegisterView.as_view(), name='rest_register'),
    url(r'^verify-email/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='rest_verify_email'),
    url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(),
        name='account_confirm_email'),
]
```

As you can see both included urls.py urlpatterns have a view named 'account_confirm_email'.

Somewhere in the code this is ran:

```
url = reverse(
            "account_confirm_email",
            args=[emailconfirmation.key])
```

Since `customer_portal.urls` is included before `rest_auth.registration.urls`, I expect the route `account_confirm_email` in `customer_portal.urls` to be returned by the above `reverse` method. But instead I get the `rest_auth.registration.urls` route URL.

Just to be sure I commented out the route in `rest_auth.registration.urls`, and then I did get the correct URL (customer_portal URL) returned.

It is filled into an email, I check that email and see that I have the wanted url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm-email/......./`, instead of: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/...../`

Can anyone tell me why the `customer_portal` URL isn't the one being reversed in both cases?

Django docs say:

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.